# A company is posting under my name on Facebook

Tags: facebook

How do I stop a company from posting on friends' timeline, pretending to be me:

"Awesome news Jake, I'm already 18 pounds thinner! For the past few weeks I have lost so much extra weight. I have been taking these new Raspberry drops I saw on Dr Oz. It really worked for me, let me know how it works for you :D Check the site out http://apps.facebook.com/117637701729217/"

I changed my password, but I don't know if this is sufficient.  These are showing up on friends' timeline and on my homepage (not on my timeline).

Answer (score 5):

From the Facebook interface, click on the arrow pointing down on the top-right next to "home".

Click "privacy settings", then go to "Ads, Apps and Websites", click "edit settings", then click edit settings for "Apps you use".

Find the app that is sending these posts and remove it.